# How to solve sudoers path problem in yocto

Tags: path, yocto, sudo, dpkg, sudoers

On my Yocto image (with .deb packaging) i set up sudo an it work's fine. Only when i try to install a .deb package with:

```
sudo dpkg -i package-name.deb
```

It results in:

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

I already did as workaround in /etc/sudoers manually:

```
## Uncomment to use a hard-coded PATH instead of the user's to find commands    
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

And after that *sudo dpkg* worked

**The question now is:**

How to do it in yocto build to have this solved out of the box ? How can I change the /etc/sudoers file to have this setup as default in the build? Or are there any other solutions ?

Thank's a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch the sudoers file at some point during the Yocto build.

Probably the most straightforward way to do so is to add `recipes-extended/sudo/sudo%.bbappend` in a custom layer which consists of the following:

```
# recipes-extended/sudo/sudo%.bbappend

do_install:append () {
    sed -i 's/# \(Defaults secure_path.*$\)/\1/' ${D}${sysconfdir}/sudoers
}
```

This bbappend simply adds a step to the `do_install` stage which uses `sed` to uncomment any line in sudoers beginning with `# Defaults secure_path`.